# I have a php register page where I want to return errors in case there are any

Tags: php

my php code checks for example if the username that is introduced by the user is already in use. If so I want to diplay an error at the bottom of the register form that sais so. Is there any way to do this only by using html,css,php?

This is my php code

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["submit-register"])) {

    require "dbh.inc.php";

    $fname = $_POST["FirstName"];
    $lname = $_POST["LastName"];
    $username = $_POST["uid"];
    $email = $_POST["mail"];
    $password = $_POST["pwd"];
    $passwordRepeat = $_POST["pwd-repeat"];

    if (empty($username) || empty($email) || empty($password) || empty($passwordRepeat) || empty($fname) || empty($lname)) {
        header("Location: ../register.php?error=emptyfields&uid=" . $username . "&mail=" . $email);//returning Emoty fields error
        exit();
    } else if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $username) && !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $fname) && !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $lname)) {
        header("Location: ../register.php?error=invalidemailandusername");//returning invalid email and username error
        exit();
    } else if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        header("Location: ../register.php?error=invalidemail&uid=" . $username . "&FirstName=" . $fname . "&LastName=" . $lname);//returning only invalid email error
        exit();
    } else if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $username)) {
        header("Location: ../register.php?error=invalidusername&mail=" . $email . "&FirstName=" . $fname . "&LastName=" . $lname);//returning invalid username error
        exit();
    } else if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $fname)) {
        header("Location: ../register.php?error=invalidFirstName&mail=" . $email . "&uid=" . $username . "&LastName=" . $lname);//returning invalid first name error
        exit();
    } else if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $lname)) {
        header("Location: ../register.php?error=invalidLastName&mail=" . $email . "&uid=" . $username . "&FirstName=" . $fname);//returning invalid last name error
        exit();
    } else if ($password !== $passwordRepeat) {
        header("Location: ../register.php?error=passwordsdonotmatch&uid=" . $username . "&mail=" . $email . "&FirstName=" . $fname . "&LastName=" . $lname);//returning passswords do not match error
        exit();
    } else {

        $sql = "SELECT uidUsers FROM users WHERE uidUsers=?";
        $sqlemail = "SELECT emailUsers FROM users WHERE emailUsers=?";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
            header("Location: ../register.php?error=sqlerror&mail=" . $email);
            exit();
        } else {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $username);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
            $resultCheck = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
            if ($resultCheck > 0) {
                header("Location: ../register.php?error=useralredadytaken&mail=" . $email);//returning username already taken error
                exit();
            } else {
                if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sqlemail)) {
                    header("Location: ../register.php?error=sqlerror&mail=" . $uid);
                    exit();
                } else {
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $email);
                    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                    mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
                    $resultCheck = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
                    if ($resultCheck > 0) {
                        header("Location: ../register.php?error=emailalredadyinuse&uid=" . $username);//returning email taken error
                        exit();
                    } else {
                        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (uidUsers, emailUsers, pwdUsers, fnUsers, lnUsers) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
                        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
                        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
                            header("Location: ../register.php?error=sqlerror");
                            exit();
                        } else {
                            $hashedpassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssss", $username, $email, $hashedpassword, $fname, $lname);
                            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

                            header("Location: ../login.php?register=succes");
                            exit();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    mysqli_close($conn);
} else {
    header("Location: ../register.php");
    exit();
}
```

[The register page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKMvr.png)

And if it is possible I would like to return the fields that were introduced corectly back to the register page in the inputs. So the user does not have to complete the whole form again. Only the part that gave the error and the password.

Comment: "Is there any way to do this only by using html,css,php"...yes, just use the `echo` command.

Comment: "I would like to return the fields that were introduced corectly back to the register page in the inputs. So the user does not have to complete the whole form again"...in that case it would be better not to redirect the user when there is an error, just include the PHP script in the same file as the HTML form, so that it can re-echo the submitted values back into the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Most times when I validate forms I put the errors in an array.
Put the php code and the form in 1 php file.

I use only if statements like

```
$errors = [];    
if ($fname == '') {
  $errors[] = 'Enter your firstname!';
}
if ($lname == '') {
  $errors[] = 'Enter your lastname!';
}
```

Before adding a user to the database you check if errors is empty

```
if (empty($errors)) {
 // add user
}
```

In the html form ill do a loop through my errors array

```
foreach ($errors as $error) {
  echo '<p>' . $error . '</p>';
}
```

Before the `if (isset($_POST["submit-register"])) {` you can also do

```
$fname = isset($_POST['fname ']) ? $_POST['fname '] : '';
```

In your form you can use $fname in the value tag so the user don't have to reenter every thing

Comment: how can I pass the array from my register.inc.php page to my register.php page? since my html form is not on the page where i built the array

Comment: include the script in register.php will help i think, like you do with your database script. Make sure $errors is defined before isset($_post) or use if isset before the each loop to prevent undefined error